# Ubuntu14.04LTS + VMware Workstation11 missing Linux-Header

Tags: kernel, vmware-workstation

I am running a VServer with Provider Strato.de from Germany... As it seem they are providing their VServer Plattforms out of Virtuozzo Containers.

My Server using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit, access via VNC4Servers and SSH.
Everything works nice, but as I try to install VMware Workstation 11.1 for Linux, VMware is asking for the Kernel Header Files.

`uname -r` returns: `13.3.0-042stab092.3`

Kernel update is not possible due to Virtuozzo environment.
The Linux header files are not avail via `apt-get` and I can't find them anywhere else in Internet to process manually.

Has somebody access to this files and can show me where to get them, or had same problem and knows how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look somewhere here (openvz download site): 
http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches

In particular, mb you need this one: http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches/rhel6-2.6.32/042stab092.3/

In any case you have to find headers from the same source you took the kernel itself.